# How to bind Microsoft SQL Server client for Node.js response data to Vue.js data object

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server client for Node.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) to fetch data from my SQL server

Here is my client-side code

```
var demo = new Vue({
        el: '#demo',
        data: {
            searchQuery: '',
            gridColumns: ['Source', 'SourceNo', 'TaskType'],
            gridData: []
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.loadData();
        },
        methods: {
            loadData: function () {
                var ip = location.host;
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'http://' + ip + '/sql',
                    data: {
                    },
                    success: function (responseData) {
                        this.gridData = responseData.recordsets;
                        console.log(this.gridData);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log('error', error);
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
```

Here is the `responseData` from my server

[image: response object from server]

Unfortunately, I don't get what object should I bind to `this.gridData`

Comment: I think you want either `responseData.recordset` or `responseData.recordsets[0]`. Assuming you were looking for 53 rows of grid data.

Comment: I know for sure that the object that I get from the server has the data that I need. Tried both `responseData.recordset` and `responseData.recordsets[0]`. No success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `success` callback, `this` no longer represents the Vue instance so you're not actually setting your observable `gridData`.

Grab a reference to the current instance and use it inside your callback:

```
var self = this;
$.ajax(...)
    success: function(responseData) {
        self.gridData = ...
    ...
    }
```